My question is regarding dependency injection through the constructor in javascript
What is the difference between passing references as public or private in dependency injection?
constructor(private route: Router, public service: UserService){

 }

bearing in mind that we will only use that reference in that specific component

Encapsulation. Saving typing. Avoiding keyboard wear-and-tear. Preventing devastating fingernail injuries.

I understand that it is about encapsulation, but wouldn't it be the same to put 'private' where 'public' is there in the code? The main question is whether this affects any specific changes @Dai

private means they're encapsulated, public means they're not. Now consider that software-components (in a general, abstract sense) should be loosly-coupled - so a type should not exposing any of its internal dependencies like that because it's inviting other types to become unnecessarily coupled to it. So for DI services, those should always be private.
